# Passing a querystring to an Ajax loaded Jquery modal dialog

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I've seen examples of how to do this, but everything I've come across is for .net or PHP pages.  I'm trying to do this with a classic ASP page and I'm new to JQuery so I'm trying to figure out how to go about it.

I have a link that will open a JQuery modal dialog.  The "open" function for the modal dialog brings in it's content from a separate .asp page.  That content I'd like to be loaded by querystring elements.

I've tested it out and got it working by entering a static querystring.  But I'm not sure how to pass a dynamic value to the string, or how to pass multiple values (meaning a querystring with "&" in it).

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
$("#example2").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 650,
            modal: true,

            open: function() {
            //here's where I need to dynamically pass multiple elements
            $("#example2").load("test.asp?id=28&value=30");}
        });

        $("#showdialog2")
            .click(function () {
                $("#example2").dialog("open");
                return false;

        });
});
```

The link that triggers it and the dialog div:

```
<a href="" id="showdialog2">Show the Dialog</a>

<div id="example2" title="My First Ajax Dialog2"></div>
```

Since this is a classic ASP page, is there a way I can pass the querystring elements from the "Show Dialog" link to the dialog open call?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how I can pass the querystring elements using that link without setting the href to a full page address.  Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do this:

```
<a href="/some/link/for/progressive/enhancement.asp?id=<%= id %>" id="showdialog2" data-id="<%= id %>">Show the Dialog</a>

<div id="example2" title="My First Ajax Dialog2"></div>
```

To add more variables, use more custom attributes and modify the below to include the extra ones.

```
$(function () {
    $("#example2").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 650,
        modal: true,

        open: function() {

    });

    $("#showdialog2")
        .click(function () {
            $("#example2").dialog("open");
            $("#example2").load("test.asp?id=" + $(this).attr('data-id') + "&value=30");}
            return false;

    });
});
```

The alternative is to use `$(this).href()` and manually parse the value to extract the querystring (you could probably regex it), but using custom attributes is an easier way forward.

You can probably chain the `open` and `load` calls and it would be a good idea to set a default content for the dialog if you're not going to destroy it on close.  Let me know if you want examples of those.

---

Chaining (note also the `preventDefault` instead of return false):

```
$("#showdialog2").click(function (event) {
    $("#example2").html('<div style="text-align: center"><img src="/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>')
        .dialog("open")
        .load("test.asp?id=" + $(this).attr('data-id') + "&value=30");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

That will reset the dialog on click to have just an ajax spinner in there ([get yours here](http://www.ajaxload.info/)), so you can re-use without a reload.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.  I tried it with this to test it out: <a href="#" id="showdialog2" data-id="3">Show the Dialog</a>.  The rest of the code I kept the same.  The dialog is opening fine and test.asp within the dialog is just response.write-ing the id from the querystring but it's saying "undefined".  Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Nevermind it's working now! I didn't notice the change you made to moving the load function into the #showDialog2 section.  If you able to provide examples of what you were referring to in your last paragraph I'd definitely appreciate it.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Added example which puts an ajax spinner in the dialog whilst waiting for the content to load.

Comment: Thanks for the added notes! I got that working now too.  This is great, I really appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying use the current querystring collection you could do something like this

```
<% 
Sub outputQueryString()
    dim key
    for each key in Request.Querystring
        Response.Write key & "=" & Request.Querystring(key) & "&"
    next
End Sub
%>


$("#example2").load("test.asp?<% outputQueryString() %>");}
```

Comment: That's great to know, thanks.  But what I'd like to do is pass new querystring elements to the load function.  I'm going to have a few links on the page and I'd like the links to contain ID numbers and other values so that when they're clicked the load function would receive those values and use them to load the proper content into the dialog.  I hope I'm being clear.  Thanks again for the suggestion.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? Could you post an example of a link containing an ID number that you wish to appear in the dialogue get request.

Comment: Sure.  I'm not sure how I'd do it in this situation, but usually I'd have a link like this: <a href="anotherPage.asp?id=<%response.write id%>">click here</a> which would load anotherPage.asp that could read the querystring and load content based on the id value.  But now that I'm using a modal dialog, I want the link to be able to pass that id value to the dialog in it's own page and the dialog to be able to load the content from anotherPage.asp which reads the querystring it's passed.  I hope that was clear. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @NicholasMurray You can just `<%= Request.QueryString %>` there is no need for the sub or to loop and the loop will break if any QS element doesn't have a value.

Comment: @RichardBenson - I know this! ;-> I was just using it as an example. Anyhow I had interpretated the question in the wrong way....